# angular function in ng-show with a promise getting error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, digest, angular-promise, ng-show

I'm using restangular for my app. Say I have this in my view:

```
<div ng-repeat="resource in resources">
    <i ng-show="isCheckedLabel(resource)" class="fa fa-checked"> Checked </i>
</div>
```

and in my controller I have my api call to the service

```
$scope.getResources = function(){
    $scope.getResourcePromise = ResourceService.getResourceById($stateParams.id).then(function(response){
        $scope.resources = response;
    });
};
```

and here is my check function which will return true or false

```
$scope.isCheckedLabel = function(resource){
    $scope.getResourcePromise.then(function(){
        for(var group in resource.groups){
            for(i = 0; i < resource.groups.length; i++){
                if (resource.groups[group].isChecked === true){
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    });
};
```

What i'm trying to do: loop through each group and if 1 or more is 'checked' I want my label in the front end to show checked.

My function is returning true when one of them is checked and false when none are checked but it's not displaying the i element in the view because I'm getting this error in the console:

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
```

and it just keeps firing over and over. What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost thing is a value returned inside async `then` callback will not be the return value of `isCheckedLabel`.

Looking at your code, you do not need `$scope.getResourcePromise.then` in `isCheckedLabel` as the you already have the resource object passed as parameter. Also for loop code seems to wrong. Change it to

```
$scope.isCheckedLabel = function(resource){
        for(var group in resource.groups){
           if (group.isChecked === true){
              return true;
           } else {
              return false;
          }
        }
};
```

Comment: Thanks @DeepakN this solution worked... I thought I already tried this and was getting an undefined error but I forgot I had the $scope.isCheckedLabel() at the bottom of my controller and was executing before the promise resolved.

Comment: Your loop still seems wrong to me, it will only check the first value as you necessarily have a `return` statement at the first iteration

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs only when you trying to update the dom when the $digest is running. In your case you can try to set the checked variable as another property in the $scope variable resources.

```
$scope.getResources = function () {
    $scope.getResourcePromise = ResourceService.getResourceById($stateParams.id).then(function (response) {
        $scope.resources = response;
        $scope.resources.forEach(function (resource) {
            $scope.getResourcePromise.then(function () {
                for (var group in resource.groups) {
                    for (i = 0; i < resource.groups.length; i++) {
                        if (resource.groups[group].isChecked === true) {
                            //Here setting another property on the resource object
                            resource.checked = true;
                        } else {
                            resource.checked = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
};
```

Now in HTML you can do something like this simply:

```
<div ng-repeat="resource in resources">
    <i ng-show="resource.checked" class="fa fa-checked"> Checked </i>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting solution, I like it. However I'm posting the entire object in other parts of my application. I'd prefer avoiding adding properties to my resource object. I'm ganna try using angular.copy() to avoid changing the original object.